# Репозиторий не содержит файла jammy Release

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, deb

При попытки обновить apt всё валится с такой ошибкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой файл в sourse.list.d
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Помогло постое удаление файла `danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-jammy.list`, так как в том репозитории не существовало папки `jammy`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]